# SPDIF auto gets unmuted

Tags: sound

Starting an applications with audio un-mutes the master output.
This only happens when i'm using coax S/PDIF out, not with analog or headphones.
I'm on 15.10, but have experienced this on previous versions as well.

Anyone know a solution or should i file a bug report?